# Customize arrows and dots with jquery plugin slick carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I customize the next and previous arrows in the slick carousel jquery plugin?  I tried modifying the slick.css file but I am getting strange results.

I want to add custom images for the arrows and dots as well as modify the margins between the slider and the arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the element and you'll see for the buttons:

```
class="slick-prev slick-arrow"
```

That class also has a pseudo element with the image on (check the content: "←";. To override you can do in your own css.

```
.slick-prev{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:url(/url/to/your/image.png);
}

.slick-prev:before{
  content:none;

}
```

That way you remove the current arrow and place a background image inside the button. Or you could put a background image on the pseudo-tag as well.